# The HCF of two numbers is $13$ and their LCM is $4095$. If one of the numbers is $819$, find the other numbers

Tags: natural-numbers

Stuck on this question. My Workings:

$$4095 = 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 13$$
$$819 = 3^2 *7 * 13$$

and I'm lost after this part. Help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the product of gcd and lcm of two numbers $a,b$ equals $ab$. So the product is 
$$
ab=13\cdot 4095.
$$
Now $a=819$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If the numbers are $a$, $b$ then:

$$\text{HCF}(a,b)*\text{LCM}(a,b)=a*b$$